# Particle container support with Graphics

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Is it possible to use the Particle Container including Graphics objects instead of sprites in Pixi.js? If i use the Graphics class an exception will be thrown because of the missing texture.

```
TypeError: e[0]._texture is undefined
```

The goal is to use the fast rendering performance of the particle container to display a massive amount of graphical elements (e.g. rectangle, circle, polygons).

```
var group = new PIXI.ParticleContainer(2000, {scale: true, position: true, rotation: true});

for(var i=0; i <1000; i++)
{
  var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
      graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xef7975, 1);
      graphics.beginFill(0xef7975, 1);
      graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
      graphics.endFill();

      //Add Positioning, rotation, or scaling
      //....
      group.addChild(graphics);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a bit more of your work?
Also, have you tried priming the definition in question by assigning a _texture of any kind (depending on how you proceed, maybe just an empty dummy) to your object?

Comment: I tried to define the _texture property and the next error is thrown: `TypeError: s.anchor is undefined` The additional code snippet can be seen as an example implementation. The error will be thrown if you try to add the graphic element to the group container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ne possibility would be to use the generateTexture(resolution, scaleMode) function of the Graphics class. This texture can be used to instantiate a sprite and to add this to the particle container.

```
var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(this.graphics.generateTexture(this.width * this.height, PIXI.scaleModes.DEFAULT));
    group.addChild(sprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the graphics to a texture do this:

```
let texture = renderer.generateTexture( graphic );
```

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/lonelydatum/pen/eggEje?editors=0010#0